# How can I connect two of my components to share data in react

Tags: reactjs, components, react-component

So I have a class component "Class1" and a function component "Function1".
I have a function in Class1 that I want to be activated when I click on a button in the Function1. This is my code:
Class1:

```
export default class Class1 extends React.Component {
 reset = () => {
    const array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 205; i++) {
      array.push(randomVals(10, 500));
    }
    this.setState({ array });
  };

 
}
```

Function1:

```
const Function1 = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
          <button className="subButton" onClick={this.props.reset()}>
            Generate Array
          </button>
.
.
.
```

I want the "Generate Array" button to call the "Reset" function

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you would need to just pass your reset function into your Function1 component when you render your Class1 component:

```js
export default class Class1 extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      Array: []
    }
    
    this.resetArray = this.resetArray.bind(this);
  }

  resetArray() {
    const array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 205; i++) {
      array.push(randomVals(10, 500));
    }
    this.setState({ Array: array });
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <p>Awesome HTML content!</p>
        <Function1 
          resetArray={this.resetArray}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }  
}
```

And I usually don't have function components, I really don't see the benefit VS a regular, old-school component :P BUt I believe it would be something like this:

```js
const Function1 = ({ resetArray }) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <button className="subButton" onClick={() => resetArray()}>
          Generate Array
        </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```